# Linq. Anonymous type error when joining to multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-5

Im trying to return an IQueryable based on my model.

But I need to join to the same lookup table twice. Then return the query variable to the gridview.

```
public IQueryable<Benchmark> GetBenchMarks([QueryString("hydrant")] string hydrant,
[QueryString("revdate")] string revdate, [QueryString("street")] string street,
[QueryString("quadrant")] string quadrant, [QueryString("desc")] string desc) {

    IQueryable<Benchmark> query = from p in _db.Benchmarks
    join s in _db.Streets on p.Street1Number equals s.Id
    join s2 in _db.Streets on p.Street2Number equals s2.Id
    select new {
        Street1Name = s.StreetName,
        p.OrderNumber,
        p.HydrantNumber,
        Street2Name = s2.StreetName,
        p.RevisionDate,
        p.Quadrant,
        p.Description,
        p.Street1Number
    };
}
```

So there is a red squiggle line on the 2nd join to s2.  And the following error.

> `Error    5   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable<Benchmarks.Model.Benchmark>'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    C:\Projects\Benchmarks\Benchmarks\Benchmarks_Home.aspx.cs   63  25  Benchmarks`

Comment: You're not returning objects of type `Benchmark`.  For instance, you have renamed `Street1Number` to `Street1Name`, and `Street2Number` to `Street2Name` (and you're using an anonymous type instantiation).  You need to create a second class type for returning this data with the street lookups applied.

Answer (score 2):

Since you end your query with `select new {...}`, you are creating an anonymous object for each result. Instead, use `select p`, and each result will be a `Benchmark`.

However, it looks like returning a `Benchmark` is not what you want. In this case, you would want to change query to be of type `IQueryable` or `IQueryable<dynamic>` (and probably change the return type of the `GetBenchMarks` function as well, unless it does return `IQueryable<Benchmark>`!).

A second (potentially better) alternative would be to create a class to represent this anonymous type, and use that.

Comment: Im essentially returning a result set of type <benchmark> and <street> because I need the StreetName field from the Street entity.  The benchmark entity is a details table that contains two seperate streetnumbers.  Originally I was just returning the benchmark entity.  I suppose I have to adjust the return type to be something that is flexible.  As far as using select p vs select new, I had some syntax issues with that but your reasoning is understood.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your query is `IEnumerable` of anonymous objects, thus it cannot be converted to `Benchmark`.

If you want to set some additional properties (`Street1Name` - that are evidently not mapped on DB) from joined relations you can do:

```
 IQueryable<Benchmark> query = from p in _db.Benchmarks
            join s in _db.Streets on p.Street1Number equals s.Id
            join s2 in _db.Streets on p.Street2Number equals s2.Id
        select new { 
                 ....
        };
 var ex = query.ToList();
 var result = new List<Benchmark>();
 foreach(bn in ex){
      result.Add(new Benchmark{ OrderNumber = bn.OrderNumber .... });
 }
// return result.AsQueryable();   
// but now it losts the point to return it as queryable, because the query was already executed so I would simply reurn that list
 return result;
```

Another option is to make new class representing the object from the query and return it from the method like:

```
... select new LoadedBenchmark { Street1Name = s.StreetName ....}
```